# Monte Carlo simulation for OTM options under stochastic volatility

Tags: options, stochastic-processes, monte-carlo, pricing, heston

I'm looking to simulate the stochastic price and volatility process (Heston model) using some form of Euler method for Monte Carlo approximation of option prices. The results that I get are acceptable for deep in the money options and at the money options but not very satisfying at all for deep out of the money options. I want to reduce the variance for faster convergence and the importance sampling method seems suitable but the problem doesn't seem to be trivial at all.

Does anyone have an idea or reference on where to start?

Comment: Most of what you have asked for here is available via QuantLib - is that a possibility? It has interfaces into many languages, can simulate Heston processes and price vanilla options either using the semi-analytical expression or via Monte Carlo.

Comment: Unless your question is purely academically driven (i.e. to learn more about importance sampling for Heston), I strongly recommend @StackG 's proposal.

Comment: You *could* try to find some potential hints at this in the literature. A quick search came up with this summary paper with examples : https://www.degruyter.com/view/journals/math/15/1/article-p679.xml

Comment: @StackG I have already coded the stochastic processes and calibration myself so QuantLib is not needed. Afaik QuantLib doesn't have any variance reduction methods implemented. I could be wrong though.

Comment: @Kermittfrog I have read that paper already but they have addressed the problem of slow convergence for MC simulations very briefly with a simple antithetic variables approach. I don't have slow convergence problems all across the board though. In fact, pricing of deep ITM and ATM options are very good but as expected deep OTM options perform poorly. My discretization scheme is by Zhu (2010) and similar to the QE scheme presented in the paper.

Comment: What options are you pricing? For plain vanillas, you don't even need to do MC, there is an analytical solution. Can you let us know what your objectives are here? Makes it easier to out a useful answer together.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of two ingredients:

- make sure your discretization in time respects the forward by adjusting the discrete rates properly (see [Exact Forward in Monte-Carlo](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2264327))
- use the forward price as control variate to make sure the forward  of the simulation matches the market forward.

With those two, the absolute error in price of OTM and ITM vanilla options should match as per the put-call parity relationship.